# I'm confused with Event Handler Callback function as a class method?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I know this may seems silly but I'm a beginner and I just need to make sure that I understand it well:

In JavaScript when I define an event listener, the callback function is called without () to prevent immediate execution, like the below example:

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click',eventHandler)

function eventHandler() {
    alert('clicked')}
```

my confusion is if implemented the above in a class and defined the `eventHandler` callback function as a method, I have to use () when I call it, like the below example:

```
class home {
    constructor(){
       this.button = document.querySelector('#button')
       this.clickEvent()
    }

    //events
   clickEvent(){
       //here i have to use eventHandler() not eventHandler
       this.button.addEventListener('click',()=>this.eventHandler())
    }
    //method
    eventHandler(){
        alert('clicked')
    }
   
}

new home()
```

Answer (score 1):

In code snippet with class, you are passing a function to `addEventListener` function which then calls the `eventHandler` function.

`() => this.eventHandler()` is an arrow function which executes `this.eventHandler()` inside its body

if you remove the arrow function then you will have to pass the name of the function instead of calling it

```
this.button.addEventListener('click', this.eventHandler)
```

**Edit:**

keep in mind that if the `eventHandler` method uses `this`, then you may run into problems because of how value of `this` is set in different cases.

Currently, `eventHandler` function isn't using `this` but you should read [how to access correct this inside callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

Comment: That generally isn't true, since class methods usually depend on the value of `this`, which will be lost if you just pass the function itself. (That isn't the case in this over simplified example though)